# AWS ecs scheduled task with cloudwatch

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am trying to create scheduled task with cloudwatch.
I am using this page

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-events-rule-target.html

The problem i see is when i run task normally then aws asks

1. vpc
2. subnets
3. Launchtype

BUT when i use cloudwatch target then it dont ask for vpc, subnets etc. why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

CloudFormation has not been updated to accommodate some Fargate functionality yet. If you get an error while trying to deploy an ECS task from CloudFormation,
try using the command line interface ([aws events put-target](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/events/put-targets.html#synopsis)) instead, which allows you to add a target that contains the required ECS parameters for launch type and network config.

Here is an example of how I configured my ECS tasks to be deployed from the CLI instead of CloudFormation:

  1. Add vpc/subnet config to a variable, `NETWORK_CONFIGURATION`:

```
NETWORK_CONFIGURATION='{"awsvpcConfiguration":{"AssignPublicIp":"ENABLED","SecurityGroups": \["'${AWS_NETWORKCONFIG_SECURITY_GROUP}'"],"Subnets":["'${AWS_NETWORKCONFIG_SUBNET}'"]}}'
```

2. Run the following command to deploy your task, which will take the vpc config from the variable declared above

```
aws events put-targets \
--rule events-rule--${TASK_NAME} \
--targets '{"Arn":"arn:aws:ecs:'${AWS_REGION}':'${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}':cluster/ecs-cluster-1","EcsParameters":{"LaunchType":"FARGATE","NetworkConfiguration":'${NETWORK_CONFIGURATION}',"TaskCount": 1,"TaskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:'${AWS_REGION}':'${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}':task-definition/ecs-task-'${TASK_NAME}'"},"Id": "ecs-targets-'${TASK_NAME}'","RoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::'${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}':role/ecsEventsRole"}' \
;
```